# How to solve missing ) after argument list in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to return a String from the controller to the client JSP and storing it in a variable.

The value which I am returning is `02:30:00,05:23:00`, but it's throwing a    "SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list" error.

I am getting value in this alert

```
alert(<%=interviewTime1%>);
```

Comment: `alert('<%=interviewTime1%>');`

Answer (score 3):

Enclose the value in quotes:

```
alert("<%=interviewTime1%>");
```

Answer (score 2):

You need quotes around the string:

```
alert('<%= interviewTime1 %>');
```